# Read unstructured data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have the following unstructured data in a text file, which is message log data from Discord.

```
[06-Nov-19 03:36 PM] Dyno#0000

{Embed}
Server
**Message deleted in #reddit-feed**
Author: ? | Message ID: 171111183099756545

[12-Nov-19 01:35 PM] Dyno#0000

{Embed}
Member Left
@Unknown User
ID: 171111183099756545

[16-Nov-19 11:25 PM] Dyno#0000

{Embed}
Member Joined
@User
ID: 171111183099756545
```

Essentially my goal is to parse the data and extract all the join and leave messages then plot the growth of members in the server. Some of the messages are irrelevant, and each message block has varying length of rows too.

```
Date        Member-change
4/24/2020   2
4/25/2020   -1
4/26/2020   3
```

I've tried parsing the data in a loop but because the data is unstructured and has varying lengths of rows, I'm confused on how to set it up. Is there a way to ignore all blocks without "Member Joined" and "Member Left"?

Comment: This seems like something you'll need to build rather than using a built-in method. Something like `with open(file) as f: data=f.readlines(); for line in f: if line.startswith('{')...`. It would be very helpful to see what you've tried so far

Comment: You can't really "ignore" the text, you'll have to search it for the string(s) you're looking for. Can you post a small sample of the code you're using to parse and gather data.

Answer (score 1):

It is structured text, just not in the way you are expecting.
A file can be structured if the text is written in a consistent format even though normally we think of structured text as field-based.

The fields are separated by a date-based header, followed by the `{embed}` keyword, followed by the command you are interested in.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from itertools import count

# Get rid of the newlines for convenience
message = message_log.replace("\n", " ")

# Use a regular expression to split the log file into records
rx = r"(\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2})"
replaced = re.split(rx, message)

# re.split will leave a blank entry as the first entry
replaced.pop(0)

# Each record will be a separate entry in a list 
# Unfortunately the date component gets put in a different section of the list
# from the record is refers to and needs to be merged back together
merge_list = list()

for x, y in zip(count(step=2), replaced):
    try:
        merge_list.append(replaced[x] + replaced[x+1])
    except:
        continue

# Now a nice clean record list exists, it is possible to get the user count
n = 0
for z in merge_list:
    # Split the record into date and context
    log_date = re.split("(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2})", z)
    # Work out whether the count should be incremented or decremented
    if "{Embed} Member Joined" in z:
        n = n + 1
    elif "{Embed} Member Left" in z:
        n = n - 1
    else:
        continue
    # log_date[1] is needed to get the date from the record
    print(log_date[1] + " " + str(n))
```